# change layout_height by dp ,but it's not fix in different devices.why?

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android, android-drawable

in my application i use a list view that i change its layout_height by dp . the problem is when i run my application on the emulator,the list view has a good view on the virtual machine. but when i run on my mobile (galaxy y ),it's not fix with my mobile.please help me.

here is my xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="335dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/item_border_selected" 
    >

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving height in dp then also it's height will remain device dependent.Instead,you should use wrapcontent or matchparent so that listview will look similar on different devices.